# Twain Failure Description

Tags: c#, 64-bit, twain

I am using Windows 8.1 x64
After a long time search I could not find any answer for my question. I try to use Twain for scanning. My application works correctly in x86 mode. But for some reason, I'm now forced to switch to "`AnyCPU`". So that I'm trying to use new 'TWAINDSM.dll' instead of 'twain_32.dll'. But it fails while initializing: "`TwRC.Failure`" in:

```
    TwainNative.DSMparent(this._Appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Parent, TwMSG.OpenDSM, ref hwndp);
```

which _Appid is

```
    this._Appid = new TwIdentity
                  {
                      Id = IntPtr.Zero,
                      Version = {MajorNum = 1, MinorNum = 1, Language = LanguageUSA, Country = CountryUSA, Info = "Mohammad"},
                      ProtocolMajor = TwProtocol.Major,
                      ProtocolMinor = TwProtocol.Minor,
                      SupportedGroups = (int)(TwDG.Image | TwDG.Control),
                      Manufacturer = "Kod Efisien Sdn Bhd",
                      ProductFamily = "TWAIN 32 Scanner",
                      ProductName = "ScanSoft"
                  };
```

in log file:

> [151040065 dsm.cpp   399   183 0000000000002174] TWAIN Working Group
>
> [151040065 dsm.cpp   400   183 0000000000002174] TWAIN 64 Source
>   Manager (Image Acquisition Interface)
>
> [151040065 dsm.cpp   401   183 0000000000002174] version: 2, 3, 0, 0
>
> [151040065 dsm.cpp  2368   183 0000000000002174]  -> DSM
>
> [151040065 dsm.cpp  2377   183 0000000000002174]
>   DG_CONTROL/DAT_PARENT/MSG_OPENDSM
>
> [151040065 apps.cpp  347   183 0000000000002174]   AppId.ProductName
>   is empty
>
> [151040065 apps.cpp  654   183 0000000000002174]   Condition Code:
>   Data parameter out of range
>
> [151040065 dsm.cpp  2432   183 0000000000002174] TWRC_FAILURE

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have 64-bit TWAIN driver for your scanner?

Comment: Yes. Thanks friend. I found a wrapper. It works well.
http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner.aspx

Comment: Great! I actually work for Dynamsoft :D

Comment: Wow. Please to meet you, my friend

Comment: soooo is this solved? If yes please post the solution as an answer and mark your question as answered. If it's not answered please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer at that time. Sorry for taking long time to answer it. As I mentioned in above comment: It works well. [dynamsoft.com/Products/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner.aspx](http://dynamsoft.com/Products/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner.aspx)